# C# Executing multiple SQL Statements and display result n GridView

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am using VS2005 and SQL Server 2005.

I am trying to execute multiple sql statements on two sql tables, meaning which I need to do more than a single check on the two tables.

The two tables are:

*Table1*: **UserID**, **Username**.

*Table2*: **UserID**, **Status**.

The following are the checks that I need to perform, but I do not know what is the exact SQL query I need.

1. Users that exist in *Table1* should exist in *Table2*
2. Users that exist is *Table1* should not have `STATUS=DELETE` in *Table2*
3. Users that do not have `STATUS=DELETE` in Table2 should exist in *Table1*

May I know how do I form this checks in to SQL queries and execute them in my VS Sqldatasource?

After which store the results in a variable and display them in GridView table.

Thank You very much for the help.

Comment: what "results" are you looking for? All your checks are boolean

Comment: i am looking for the "result" that does not fulfill the 3 query checks, means I am looking for 

Users that exist in *Table2* but not *Table1*; 

Users that exist in *Table1* has 'STATUS=DELETE' in *Table2*;

and Users that do not have 'STATUS=DELETE' in *Table2* exists in *Table1*.

Comment: @RUiHAO Can a UserID have multiple statuses at the same time?

Comment: @BrandonMoore Good point. My default assumption was that userID was the PK in table2, but if that assumption is wrong then my solution might not be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 3 cases you want to catch:

1. User exists in table1 but not in table2
2. User is marked as DELETE in table2 but still exists in table1
3. User is NOT marked as DELETE in table2 but doesn't exist in table1

These three scenarios are covered in the WHERE clause below in that order.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
OR (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
OR (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status <> 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
```

---

**Edit:** In response to the OP's comment, here is a modified version that will insert data into `table3` based on case #1. Assume that `table3` is a table that has two columns, `userID` and `problem`.

```
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT userID, 'No Matching Table2 Record'
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: thanks alot, your sql query worked for me. I can now display the result base on the 3 cases. However, if I want to change the query to: For each case, generate an insert statement into a separate database for each issue found (because I want to add a column 'ISSUE' for each problem found, so that it is more user friendly when displaying the data). How can I change one, for e.g., the first query:
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
    WHERE (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
into an INSERT INTO statement instead?

Answer (score 0):

You want to `join` table 1 and 2 on `UserID` and exclude delete status. Then use the results in your grid view.

```
select t1.UserID, t1.Username
from Table1 t1 
     join Table2 t2 on t1.UserID = t2.UserID
where t2.Status != 'DELETE'
```

Comment: This only covers his third case (user is not marked as 'DELETE' in table2 but still exists in table 1)